# Using socket.io from inside and outside LAN

Tags: node.js, socket.io, real-time

I am using socket.io for a project that requires me to stream live data to a browser. Now the server part is fine, but on socket.io client io.connect() call, I have had a few problems in the past, without proper resolution. I have tried the usual suspects, but I am not getting through.

My client call to looks like this: 
`var socket = io.connect('http://10.95.xx.xx:5002');` 
where 10.95. .. is the IP address of the server on the LAN. Using this IP I can access the server from inside the LAN, on any machine in the LAN, but this doesn't work from outside the LAN. Problem being, most probably, that this IP is for LAN only and not the public IP. As per university's network settings, the public IP is 128.95 ...and if I change it to this IP, then it will be accessible from outside, but not from inside.

One way to resolve this, is that I try to read the client's IP address and based on that decide the parameter IP. But this doesn't feel robust. Also, I tried using `io.connect("/")` . It had worked for me in previous circumstance, but it did not this time. Also, the empty call did not work `io.connect()` did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you can use the clients IP address, this here always worked for me:

```
var port = window.location.port,
    host = window.location.hostname,
    protocol = window.location.protocol,
    path = '/',
    url, 
    options = { };

if( protocol.indexOf( 'https' ) > -1 ) {
    protocol = 'wss:';
} else {
    protocol = 'ws:'
}

url = protocol + "//" + host + ":" + port + path;

options = { };

/*
// If you wanted to add an access token, "Session" is where I store this
if( Session.token ) {
   options.query = 'access_token=' + Session.token;
}
*/

socket = io( url, options );
```

Comment: It worked perfectly from inside, still am not getting it to run from outside, must be a server issue though, I am guessing. Will update. This should be on socket.io website though. :).

Comment: Could your network be blocking from the outside? It should be over 80 or 443, but you never know with some organisations

Comment: It was the port issue, I talked to our network admin, and they only open some ports for incoming connections, so when port 80 was added, it worked from outside the LAN, i.e. over the internet, great feeling adding a device to the IoT ;).

Comment: Smallest cinch though, when I use the external IP address from inside the LAN, it doesnt work, anyway around this ?

Comment: That sounds a bit odd. Probably sound routing issues somewhere along the lines. Could you host your server on a service like Heroku?

Comment: I think its a firewall issue. About heroku, I think I cannot do that as I am reading sensor data at the server, which I transmit to the client, and getting that to heroku consistently would be a pain.

Comment: You could have the sensor server providing the heroku server with the data, which you could then also save to mongodb or something ( see mongolab ), then the client can connect to the heroku app to get its updates. All this only if you can't sort out the firewall issues.

Comment: You could also just think of the sensor "server" as another client, so you could have multiple clients serving sensor data, event the clients that are reading the data could provide some other data ( don't know the domain you are working in, so don't know the kind of data you want )

Comment: The first approach local -> mongodb -> heroku -> client will definitely work,  as I have tried it before, but maybe slow, therefore may not be suitable, for all real-time applications, the second design pattern is really interesting, and SO complains, that this is a chat. so i will stop here. thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97346/discussion-between-fabiancook-and-chintan-pathak).